# Problems with getting back rotated images from HashMap

Tags: java, image, rotation, hashmap

I have the following problems:

1. I don't know why my function, when displaying already rotated images, shows only one in as many jpanels as there were photos given.
   Let me give an example: I load 4 images into hashmap. Then I put them into my rotate function and try to display them. I end up with 4 tabs of one rotated image.
2. When I'm trying to rotate twice using the same deegres as used previously (I'm using slider to take degrees) it doesn't rotate anymore but if I touch slider and move it, the function rotates normally.
3. I had no idea how to convert an Image type into File object thus I converted it into BufferedImage and then to File. I browsed through the Internet but could not find anything helpful.

My main's class piece of code:

```
JPanel panel_2e = new JPanel();
        panel_2e.setOpaque(true);
        panel_2e.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED, Color.GRAY, Color.DARK_GRAY), "Rotate options"));
        panel_2e.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel_2e,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 360, 180);

        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(90);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider.setLabelTable(slider.createStandardLabels(45));

        JPanel radio_buttons_rotate=new JPanel();
        radio_buttons_rotate.setLayout(new BoxLayout(radio_buttons_rotate, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JCheckBox cut_frame = new JCheckBox("Cut edges");
        cut_frame.setSelected(true);
        cut_frame.addItemListener(new ItemListener()  {
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    {check = true;
                        System.out.println("Cut-edge mode selected");}
                    else
                    {check = false;
                        System.out.println("Cut-edge mode deselected");}
                }
        });
        cut_frame.setBounds(78, 41, 60, 23);
        radio_buttons_rotate.add(cut_frame);

        JRadioButton black_rdbutton = new JRadioButton("Black background");
        black_rdbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                       black = true;
                }
        });


        black_rdbutton.setBounds(78, 41, 60, 23);
        radio_buttons_rotate.add(black_rdbutton);


        JRadioButton white_rdbutton = new JRadioButton("White background");
        white_rdbutton.setSelected(true);
        white_rdbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                      black = false;
                }
        });


        white_rdbutton.setBounds(78, 41, 60, 23);
        radio_buttons_rotate.add(white_rdbutton);

        ButtonGroup group_frame_rotate = new ButtonGroup();
        group_frame_rotate.add(black_rdbutton);
        group_frame_rotate.add(white_rdbutton);

        panel_2e.add(radio_buttons_rotate);

        JLabel Rotate  = new JLabel();
        Rotate.setText(deg+"\u00b0");
        panel_2e.add(slider);
        JButton btnRotate = new JButton("Rotate");
        JPanel RotatePanel=new JPanel(); 
        RotatePanel.add(Rotate);
        RotatePanel.add(btnRotate);
        RotatePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btnRotate.setBounds(28, 158, 89, 23);
        btnRotate.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        btnRotate.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        panel_2e.add(RotatePanel);




        panel_2.add(panel_2e);
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

             public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
                 deg=((JSlider) ce.getSource()).getValue(); 

                 Rotate.setText(deg+"\u00b0");                 }

        });
        btnRotate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(AddDirectory.all_chosen.isEmpty())
                {Object[] options = {"OK"};
                int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                        "Please choose at least 1 image to rotate.","Empty work list",
                           JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                           JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                           null,
                           options,
                           options[0]);}
                else
                {RotateFunction rot = new RotateFunction(AddDirectory.all_chosen);
                rot.main();
                BufferedImage kk = null;
                        Display disp= new Display(); // invoke Display class

                        for(File i : all_chosen_images.values()){
                                try{
                                kk = ImageIO.read(new File(i.getAbsolutePath()));
                                disp.createFrame(center, i, kk); //create new frame with image 
                                }
                                catch (IOException es){
                                        es.printStackTrace();
                                }

                        }
                        }
            }
        });
```

And here is my rotate function:

```
public class RotateFunction{

    HashMap<JButton,File> map;
    Image spiral;


    RotateFunction(HashMap<JButton,File> source_of_image)
    {
            map = AddDirectory.all_chosen;
    }


     public void main(){
            int counter = 0;

            if (spiral == null){
                    for(Map.Entry<JButton, File> entry: map.entrySet())   //////Moving through hashMap
                    {
                try {
                    spiral = getImage(entry.getValue().getAbsolutePath());
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println("Path of image " + counter + " : " +entry.getValue().getAbsolutePath());  
                    if (PhotoEdit.check == true){
                        rotateImage(PhotoEdit.deg, null);
                        System.out.println("Rotating image "+counter+" by "+PhotoEdit.deg+" degrees (edge cut)");
                    }
                    else{
                        rotateImage1(PhotoEdit.deg, null);
                        System.out.println("Rotating image "+counter+" by "+PhotoEdit.deg+" degrees (bigger frame)");   
                    }
                   BufferedImage tmp = toBufferedImage(spiral);
                   File f;
                   f = new File( "image.png" );  
                   try
                   {  

                    ImageIO.write( tmp, "PNG", f );  

                   }  
                   catch ( IOException x )
                   {  
                       // Complain if there was any problem writing  
                       // the output file.  
                       x.printStackTrace();  
                   }        
                    map.put(entry.getKey(), f);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    } 
                    PhotoEdit.all_chosen_images.clear();
                    PhotoEdit.all_chosen_images.putAll(map);  //Putting HashMap with rotated images into global HashMap
                    System.out.println("Images have been successfully rotated");
            }
    }

    public Image getImage(String path){
            Image tempImage = null;
            try
            {
                    tempImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(path);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println("An error occured - " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return tempImage;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////IMAGE ROTATION /////////////////////////////////

    public void rotateImage(double degrees, ImageObserver o){
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.spiral);
            BufferedImage blankCanvas = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)blankCanvas.getGraphics();
            g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), icon.getIconWidth()/2, icon.getIconHeight()/2);
            g2.drawImage(this.spiral, 0, 0, o);
            this.spiral = blankCanvas;
    }

    public void rotateImage1(double degrees, ImageObserver o){
        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees)));
        double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees)));
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.spiral);
        int w = icon.getIconWidth();
        int h = icon.getIconHeight();
        int neww = (int)Math.floor(w*cos+h*sin);
        int newh = (int)Math.floor(h*cos+w*sin);
        BufferedImage blankCanvas = new BufferedImage(neww, newh, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)blankCanvas.getGraphics();
        g2.translate((neww-w)/2, (newh-h)/2);
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), icon.getIconWidth()/2, icon.getIconHeight()/2);
        g2.drawImage(this.spiral, 0, 0, o);
        this.spiral = blankCanvas;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image img)
    {
        if (img instanceof BufferedImage)
        {
            return (BufferedImage) img;
        }

        // Create a buffered image with transparency
        BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // Draw the image on to the buffered image
        Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
        bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        bGr.dispose();

        // Return the buffered image
        return bimage;
    }
```

}

In the display function i have the following arguments - createFrame(JDekstopPane where_to_put_the_image, File img, BufferedImage image)

HashMap - all_chosen_images is the global HashMap storing all the images

Really hope for your help.
Aleksander